# Prestashop - Fatal php error after upgrade vendor

Tags: composer-php, prestashop, upgrade, prestashop-1.7

I've seen this question already made other times, but it seems that in my case the fixes I've found are not enough.

I've just followed the manual upgrade guide from Prestashop for version 1.7.7.8, but I had to stop before upgrading the database, because the backend freezed to a blank page and the frontend is only showing this (apparently common) error:

> Warning: require_once(/home/customer/www/kalamitica.com/public_html/config/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/customer/www/kalamitica.com/public_html/config/autoload.php on line 26

> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/customer/www/kalamitica.com/public_html/config/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php73/pear') in /home/customer/www/kalamitica.com/public_html/config/autoload.php on line 26

Things I've tried
I've already checked paths (down to case sensitive), eventually missing files and permissions, but everything seems to be correct.
The cache in /var/cache has been removed as well.

Also, reading from other solutions, I've also tried running `composer-install` from SSH and that returned this error

> Composer could not find a composer.json file in [...]

And since there's already a `composer.lock` file, as someone suggested, I created an "empty" composer.json file, then sent the command again. Composer apparently made it's way through, but nothing changed: still locked back-end and same error on the front-end.

This is driving me nuts.
Thank you in advance.

P.S. At the moment I'm reverting to the previous backup, before trying again. Also, PHP Version is 7.3, that should be officially supported in PrestaShop 1.7.7.x

Comment: Have you checked all the requirements with for example PS's own tool: https://github.com/PrestaShop/php-ps-info/

Also check if the composer update (or install) actually filled the vendor folders (to check if the SSH login corresponds with your shop, sometimes this is an issue in for example DirectAdmin).

Also download the original autoload files for your version from Prestashop and replace them both (in your root folder and in the /config/ folder) check their permissions and try again.